# xcodeのプロジェクトをGithubに公開しようとしたが、言語がrubyで登録されてしまう

Tags: swift, xcode, git, github

現在、XcodeのプロジェクトをGithubに公開しようとしています。
ここで問題が起きました。
プロジェクトをGithubにあげることはできたのですが、言語がrubyで登録されてしまいました。
どうやらpodfileの言語で認識してしまったようです。
この場合はどのような操作をすれば、Swiftのファイルを正しく認識してくれるでしょうか？
回答よろしくお願いします。

上手く上げられなかったプロジェクト
https://github.com/hirokei-camel/Password.git

Comment: 言語の判定はあくまで目安であり、またブランチが更新されていけば自然と正しい結果になっていくと思われます。 / 判定は拡張子等をベースにしているので、設定ファイルを用意する方法もあります。 [Changing repository language on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54946235)

Comment: リンク先のGitHubリポジトリを見ましたが、Password[フォルダに白い矢印が表示されその中身を開くことができない](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62056294/6541007)状態になっていますね。そのせいでSwiftのソースが全く(Pod内のもの以外は)存在しないため、正しく判定されていないのだと思われます。まずは、その点を解消する必要があるでしょう。